Rails 7 - how to open a text file that is located on disk in Ubuntu?
I am running my Rails app on the Ubuntu server. The structure of files on the disk is this:
/home
  /dokku/my-rails-app
  /text-files/txt/my-file.txt

In /home/dokku/my-rails-app is my Rails app and I would like to open in this app the /home/text-files/txt/my-file.txt file.
In the view of my Rails app, I do this:
<%= File.read("/home/text-files/txt/my-file.txt") %>

and it generated error ActionView::Template::Error (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /home/text-files/txt/my-file.txt):
However, if I do the same approach in my development environment (OSX), it works and the file is properly displayed.
I also double-checked the path to the file on Ubuntu is correct and it is - if I SSH to terminal and run cat /home/text-files/txt/my-file.txt, I get the file's content.
Am I overlooking something what prevents the Rails app display the content of the file?

what's the root directory for your rails app in production?

Did you check if your Rails app has read permissions for the file. You can change the permissions of the file by running:
$ sudo chmod 644 /home/text-files/txt/my-file.txt

Worth checking as well is the file ownership. If you need to update it you can use:
$ sudo chown www-data:www-data /home/text-files/txt/my-file.txt

Check /var/log/audit/audit.log in case that you have SELinux or AppArmor. It's possible that the access is being restricted.

Hi @dmferrari, thank you for your message. 1) the txt files already have 644 permissions. 2) changing ownership doesn't work either; it's the same issue for root as well as for www-data. 3) there's nothing "suspicious" or seemingly incorrect in audit.log
